# How can I convert a PHP regex to Node.js

Tags: php, node.js

I need to convert php regex to Node.js. My PHP regex code:

`preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $script, $match);`

I'm new to Nodejs. How can I convert this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the equivalent Node.js regex

```js
/\bhttps?:\/\/[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,\p{P}\s]|\/))/gu
```

**Demo & Explanation:** https://regex101.com/r/Y2vlwe/1

Answer (score 0):

```
const regex = /\bhttps?:\/\/[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|\/))/g;
const script = "Your input here";

const matches = script.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /\bhttps?:\/\/[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,\p{P}\s]|\/))/gu;
const v = "https://www.google.com";
const v1 = "sampel text";

const matches = v.match(regex);   // matches
const matches1 = v1.match(regex); // Not matches
console.log(matches);
console.log(matches1);
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're trying to check for a valid url. easies thing in javascript is to do this:

```
  let url = 'https://gooogle.com';

  try {
   const parts = new URL(url);
   console.log(parts);

  } catch(err) {
     console.error('not a valid url', err);
  }
```

Comment: This, in and of itself, is not sufficient I don't believe to accurately indicate whether a supplied URL is valid - consider the url `ptth:\\google.con&x=1` ( which is clearly nonsense )

Comment: you could check for protocol `http`